# Php - Find attributes and their values for a Json format

Tags: php, json

I have a json array (just one row with many attributes) like this :

```
    $row = '[{"ID":"0","Name":"user","Option":"yes"}]';
```

I can access to every value with :

```
    $row->ID; $row->Name; ...
```

My question is how can I use a loop to found all attributes and their values without using :

> $obj = json_decode($row);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd argument of json_decode specified that if you give it `true`, it will return an array instead of an object.

So, if I understand your question correctly, this should be what you're looking for:

```
$row = '[{"ID":"0","Name":"user","Option":"yes"}]';
foreach (json_decode($row, true) as $key => $value) {
  echo $key . ' = ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Oh sorry. It's because they JSON is wrapped in an array.

Iterate over this: `json_decode($row, true)[0]` (PHP 5.4 only in this syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Barring the reasoning behind why you'd not just use `json_decode`... if this is as complicated as your `JSON` is going to get (just one item in the array), you can piece it apart:

```
$row = '[{"ID":"0","Name":"user","Option":"yes"}]';

$row = substr($row, 2, strlen($row) - 4); // Removes [{ and }]

$items = explode(',', $row); // Explodes into parts

$final = array();

foreach($items as $item) {
    $parts = explode(':', $item); // Key/value

    $key = substr($parts[0], 1, strlen($parts[0]) - 2); // Remove quotes
    $value = substr($parts[1], 1, strlen($parts[1]) - 2); // Remove quotes

    $final[$key] = $value;
}

var_dump($final);
```